# Setting jquery datepicker certain days of the week unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this function that will collect certain days numerical value in order to use in another function that will disable those days.

```
/* grab off days*/
function off(){
    for (var key in offDays) {
        if (offDays.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return offDays[key];

        }
     }  
 }
```

For example will return 0 , 1 for sunday and monday. Now i want to use those days to disable days on the datepicker, but when i use the following code, it only disables the first one in the order.I guess i need to loop through somehow, but how?

```
var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
//console.log('Checking (raw): ' + m + '-' + d + '-' + y);
for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) !== -1 || new Date() > date) {
        //console.log('bad:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y + ' / ' + disabledDays[i]);
        return [false];
    }
            if(date.getDay() === off()){
                return [false];
            }


}
```

Check the last if statement

Comment: what is `offDays` is it an array?

Comment: yes! ex. {"tues":2,"weds":3,"thurs":4}

Comment: also can you share `disabledDays`

Comment: var disabledDays = ["1-14-2014"]; here i can add specific dates and it will be disabled

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nj6ut/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var disabledDays = ["1-24-2014"];
var offDays = {
    "tues": 2,
    "weds": 3,
    "thurs": 4
};
var offds = $.map(offDays, function (day) {
    return day
})
$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var m = date.getMonth(),
            d = date.getDate(),
            y = date.getFullYear(),
            str = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y;
        if ($.inArray(str, disabledDays) !== -1 || new Date() > date) {
            return [false];
        }
        if ($.inArray(date.getDay(), offds) !== -1) {
            return [false];
        }
        return [true]
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nj6ut/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `beforeShowDay` function to check if given day is enabled or not like:

```
beforeShowDay: function (a) {
    var d = a.getFullYear() + '-' + (a.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + a.getDate();
    if (d==='2014-1-20') {//WILL DISABLE 20 Jan 2014
        return [false, "", "disabled date"];
    } else {
        return [true, "", ""];
    }
}
```

A working sample is here in this <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/9CKN8/)</kbd>